# Can't install the wireless driver in HP Pavilion dv2419us

Tags: 13.04, wireless, hp

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.04 in an old HP Pavilion dv2419us. The problem is, Ubuntu doesn't detect the wireless card. But it works fine in Windows 7.

The following command returns nothing!

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```

And the `lspci` output is:

```
    00:00.1 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 0 (rev a2)
00:00.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 1 (rev a2)
00:00.3 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 5 (rev a2)
00:00.4 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 4 (rev a2)
00:00.5 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:00.6 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 3 (rev a2)
00:00.7 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation C51 Memory Controller 2 (rev a2)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation C51 PCI Express Bridge (rev a1)
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C51 [GeForce Go 6150] (rev a2)
00:09.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Host Bridge (rev a2)
00:0a.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 LPC Bridge (rev a3)
00:0a.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 SMBus (rev a3)
00:0a.3 Co-processor: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PMU (rev a3)
00:0b.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:0b.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:0d.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 IDE (rev f1)
00:0e.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Serial ATA Controller (rev f1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 PCI Bridge (rev a2)
00:10.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:14.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP51 Ethernet Controller (rev a3)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
05:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
05:09.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
05:09.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 0a)
05:09.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 05)
```

The command `lspci -nn | grep 0280` gives no output.

Any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: did you try `lspci` command.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the details of your wireless card from: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` doesn't give me anything. And the wireless button is not hard blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the b43 card like the hp dv5000 has.
try this:
Either go to package magager and install linux-firmware-nonfree and run commands below or
if the package manager does not find the firmware file then goto:
packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/download
download the linux-firmware-nonfree deb file from one of the mirrors listed
go to the download folder and click on the file you downloaded it should open up in Gdebi 
if it does not then you need to install Gdebi (read here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)
once linux-firmware-nonfree is installed then:
open a terminal window and type:
sudo (modprobe -r b43) without the parenthesis 
then type: 
(sudo modprobe b43) with no paranthesis

should fix it.